# mootools - is it possible to get a useful backtrace?

Tags: mootools

SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
mootools.core.js, line 273 character 63

Mootools frequently generates errors like these that are useless in identifying the problem. Is there a way to identify how the mootools method that crashed came to be called in the first place, other than by trial-and-error? In other words, to get a backtrace, similar to PHP's `debug_backtrace()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is...

But not when you put your question together like this.

for starters, there are MANY versions of MooTools (major releases were 1.0, 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5 (latest stable)). then you can use the MooTools builder to create a custom version as well... nobody can say what is on line 273 of whatever minified version it is you use

next: don't know how you are used to developing and debugging but using minified production libraries is NOT the way to go. you should swap to the default non-compressed and minified version of mootools-core first, which will in turn show you a far more meaningful part of the code and offer a clue as to what you do.

next: this is an Internet Explorer specific error. you even fail to state that. it is NOT a MooTools error and if you google for `SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.`, you will notice all the results are normally related to jQuery, so whatever it is you are doing, it's library agnostic.

next: what are you actually doing? this error is a standard trident 'panic' response. I have seen it happen on DOM manipulation, XHR, iframe/document issues, 'unsafe' DOM changes, CORS violations, all sorts. without actually stepping through your `domready` hooks and disabling components and parts of components until the problem goes away, you cannot isolate anything. IE - in this state - will seldom let you trace / debug this. your only bet is (if it's IE8 or it happens in IE9) is to run the developer tools of IE9, pick IE8 standards mode and work with the un-minified files, then console.log() the variables around it, if the inspectors/watches are unavailable.

If you post more info, snippets, examples, people will be able to offer some actual help. Good luck, hope this gets you started. W/O supplying more information, this question will likely get closed as it is unanswerable and won't hold any value for future visitors.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It incorrectly claims that version considerations are relevant here. It incorrectly claims that the browser being IE7 is relevant here. It incorrectly claims that the specific details of what I am doing are relevant here. It then offers the advice of using trial-and-error, where the original question explicitly asks for a way to do other than trial-and-error.

Comment: version consideration matters, code won't be the same across versions. newer versions have certain bugs fixed. browser matters, you got no debug tools in IE6/7, what recommendation on tracing do you want when you don't even say it's IE. the bug itself is nondescript engine panic, has no stack (normally) so no debugging other than trial and error is available, unless you revert to non-minified code and start logging inputs and values. you did not supply any more information, what exactly is your expectation? if you were just after a yes/no answer, then pick one at random.